# Unable to catch urllib 404 Error when downloading images

Tags: python, urllib

Running python 3 with this code, I cannot for the life of me catch this 404 error. If an image is not found, `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` is raised at 
`dl_image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(cam_url, "thumbnail" + str(1 + img_num[0]) + ".jpg")`:

```
import requests
# import json
# import re
import random
import urllib
def random_cam(img_num=[0]):
    cam_url = url + camera_IDs[img_num[0]] + trailing_url
    dl_image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(cam_url, "thumbnail" + str(1 + img_num[0]) + ".jpg")
    if img_num == [0]:  # makes sure to only shuffle camera order once to avoid duplicate camera thumbnails
        random.shuffle(camera_rand)
    try:
        dl_image
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        print ("image not found or camera is offline")
        img_num[0] += 2 # skip over index that throws an error and download next image in line
        dl_image
    else:
        print (cam_url)
        img_num[0] += 1
        return img_num[0]
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: The error is raised at `dl_image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(cam_url, "thumbnail" + str(1 + img_num[0]) + ".jpg"):` place the `try` statement before that line.

Comment: @JRodDynamite That was it! Was beating myself over the head when the solution was right there in front of me, post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised at

```
dl_image = urllib.request.urlretrieve(cam_url, "thumbnail" + str(1 + img_num[0]) + ".jpg")
```

Simply place the `try` statement before that line